# Очищать текст при нажатии на картинку

Tags: android, kotlin

Хочу чтобы при фокусе на мою картинку, очищался текст

```
closeImageButton.onFocusChangeListener = OnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
        if(hasFocus) nameView.text.clear()
    }
```

Хочу заметить что с EditText'ом работало, а вот с ImageView почему то не хочет. Возможно тут какой то другой подход нужен?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может попробуете с кликом

```
closeImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            nameView.text = "";
        }
});
```